# Tabs selection from route using react-router

Tags: reactjs

I want to create tabs which will be rendered by the route.

For example on route `/path/SECURITY` I want security tab to be active and shown its content.

My question is can I do it with `react-router`? For example I have tried something like:

```
<Route path="/path" component={Page1} >
    <Route path={/path/SECURITY} component={TabsManager} TabId={eSettingsTabs.SECURITY}>
    </Route>
</Route>
```

This way i can set the active tab in `TabsManager` and render the tabs content.

And in side `TabsManager` i just render the contant:

```
<TabContentLayout>
    {this._getTabContent(this.props.route.TabId)}
</TabContentLayout>
```

My question is, is there a way to render the content from the `react-router`, for example something like:

```
<Route path="/path" component={Page1} >
    <Route path={/path/SECURITY} component={TabsManager} TabId={eSettingsTabs.SECURITY}>
        <Route path={/path/SECURITY} component={SecurityTab} TabId={eSettingsTabs.SECURITY} />
    </Route>
</Route>
```

This doesn't work of course since security tab will not be rendered

Answer (score 0):

You can use the render method to pass the route info to the tab manager without using a extra route:

```
<Route path="/path" render={routeProps=>(
    <>
        <Page1/>
        <TabsManager route={routeProps.route}/>
        <Route path={'/path/SECURITY'} component={SecurityTab} TabId={eSettingsTabs.SECURITY} />
        </Route>
    </>)}>
</Route>
```

Note you can't use more than one of render, children, or component for the same route, only one component will be rendered.